# Persistent Ignorant Domain with Entity Framework and Spacial Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-6

I'm developing an application that implements DDD and Repository Pattern as shown in diagram bellow:

[image: My Software Architecture]

I expect to keep my Domain Layer persistent ignorant, so I wouldn't like to install entity framework libraries there. The only problem I'm facing is that my application uses spatial data, but I'm not supposed to use DbGeography as a Property Type of my entities, once it belongs to System.Data.Entity.Spatial namespace, from EntityFramework assembly.

Is there a way to create a class to hold latitude, longitude and elevation values in Domain Layer, like that:

```
public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Elevation { get; set; }
}
```

and then convert that class to DbGeography in my Repository Layer?

In other words, the domain entities would have only Location class as a property:

```
public class Place : IEntityBase, ILocalizable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

and I'd convert it DbGegraphy to persist spatial data and do some calculations only in repository layer. My plans was try something like that to convert:

```
public class LocationMap : ComplexTypeConfiguration<Location>
{
    public LocationMap()
    {
        Property(l => DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", l.Longitude, l.Latitude))).HasColumnName("Location");
        Ignore(l => l.Elevation);
        Ignore(l => l.Latitude);
        Ignore(l => l.Longitude);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and never will. How I can solve this problem? What are the best practices in this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, please, take a look. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Nicely done application architecture, BTW.

Comment: `System.Data.Spatial` is a .Net namespace.

Comment: @GertArnold, For EF6, spatial classes like DbGeography and DbGeometry have moved from System.Data.Spatial to System.Data.Entity.Spatial. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469466

Comment: Ah, missed that one, thanks. I'm afraid that you have to map to DbGeography directly. The best you can do is map the EF entities to domain entities. Yes, it's an extra mapping layer, but it's hard to apply DDD principles to an EF class model anyway.

Comment: @LucasS. From what I've heard, Entity Framework is not the ideal ORM candidate for DDD. I would look at something like NHibernate that doesn't require any compromise (or very little) in the domain model or look at using a database without impedence mismatch for the write model.

Comment: @plalx, Thank you for your comment. That is my plan B. My expectations when I created this question was check if someone have a different strategy that was not considering. I have more experience with EF6 than NHibernate, so I'd like to take advantage of it.

Comment: Hi Lucas, how did you go with it? I'm facing the same issue as you. I took a look at the @Backs answer and kind of works well for my needs. Would be nice to hear from you how you solved that issue.

Comment: I just wanted to reiterate what has already been said, EF or any heavy-duty ORM is not worth the trouble when implementing DDD tactical patterns. Something like Dapper works well. I have been implementing DDD since 2012 and have used EF many times and regretted it every time. It is not that it cannot work, it is just easy to mess up and hard to back out of the choices.

Comment: I recommend to create a Value Object in domain layer to keep location data and let orm persist them. for example you can use </Component> for mapping Value Objects in nhibernate or for more advance soultion creat some custom data types in your infrastructure layer

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know "right" way, but, i have a tricky idea. I hope, it'll help you or give some more variants:
Ypu have domain entity `Place`, it's fully persistent ignorant and it's place in Domain assembly. Good.
Lets create one more Place class in Repository assembly:

```
internal sealed class EFPlace : Place
{
    DbGeography EFLocation 
    {
        get
        {
            return DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", Location.Longitude, Location.Latitude);
        }
        set
        {
            //vice versa convertion, I don't know, how to do it :)
        }
    }
}
```

We created special class for Entity Framework, and map it:

```
public class PlaceMap : ComplexTypeConfiguration<EFPlace>
{
    public PlaceMap ()
    {
        Property(p => p.EFLocation).HasColumnName("Location");
        Ignore(p => p.Location);
    }
}
```

But, we have to convert from Place to EFPlace on save in repository. You can create special constructor, or casting method.
Another variant - create partial class Place in Domain and Repository assemblies. And add needed propery in Repository one class and so on.
Well, it looks ugly :( but, I don't know "pure", real-life examples of Persistent Ignorant Domain. We always have limitations of Entity Framework. [NHibernate](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/29/entity-framework-6-7-vs-nhibernate-4-ddd-perspective/) has a little more features.